# How do I stop <nav> from splitting in the middle

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm making this navigation bar with the `<nav>` element. I have one link floating to the right and the rest floating left, to maximize the size of the navigation bar.  However, all space in between the nth-1 link and n has no background color or presence at all from what I can tell.  The code is extremely basic if someone doesn't mind looking at the result it'll make more sense.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #333;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
}
nav ul li a {
  font-size: 21px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li style='float:right;'><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set a height to either `nav` or `ul`, because it contains floating elements (and thus have no height).

```
nav {height: 60px;}
```

see this fddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cm9jsyb5/

Comment: Thank you very much, this also lets me just set the nav background-color instead of each <li>.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat it as a flexbox:

1.) Add `display: flex;`to `nav ul`. This makes all `li` elements flex items.

2.) Change the inline style in the last `li` element to `margin-left: auto`. This moves that element to the far right.

(I also changed the link text color to get a better contrast on the dark background, plus I removed quite a bit of CSS that you don't need if you use flexbox)

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: #fa0;
  font-size: 21px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li style='margin-left: auto;'><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Better than adding a fixed height, by a long way. It's worth noting the lack of support for flex in IE 9 backwards and buggy support in newer versions of IE. Edge is OK though: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You need a [clearfix](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html) on the foats. Floated elements are removed from the normal document flow, therefore the parent element collapses. There are several fixes for this, clearfix being a common approach. Another is floating the parent element.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #333;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #333;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  float: right;  
}
nav ul li a {
  font-size: 21px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

For more on this behaviour of floats, see: https://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/

Also note you can use `last-child` and get rid of the inline style.